# PHP < 5.5: password_hash compatible crypt hashing

Tags: php, bcrypt, php-password-hash

OK. I've really do a big research, but I haven't got any crypting / hashing knowledge. On my own machine I've got php 5.5 and I'm using password_hash function. I just realized, that my online hosting has the maximum of PHP 5.4.

I've got a special class for encrypting, that's why there are (hopefully) not many changes to be done. Here is my simple code:

```
class Enigma {
    public static function hash($password) {
        return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }
    public static function verify($password, $hash) {
        if (password_verify($password, $hash)) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

As You can see this is just a simple overlay, but there is a first occasion to use it. How can I replace the password_hash and password_verify function with crypt function to be compatible in the future with passrowd_ functions?

For example. Now I will do crypt(), then store the result in users database, and in the future when I will switch to password_hash and password_verify functions, I want this crypted password to work, and not forcing every user to change password.

I hope that during my research I haven't missed anything. I'm looking for simple, elegant, SAFE solution :).

Thx for You help, br

**UPDATE**: I have read this (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php):

password_hash() creates a new password hash using a strong one-way hashing algorithm. password_hash() is compatible with crypt(). Therefore, password hashes created by crypt() can be used with password_hash().

But crypt has got many options, and I;m not quite sure, if all of them are compatible.

Comment: You can use the password compatibility pack => https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Comment: OK +1, thank you very much :). Never heard of it... I like to do everything on myself, but I will give it a try.

Comment: I think that You can make a simple answer, I will accept it and maybe another persons with this problem, will have something to read. Great link.

Comment: As per your request; posted. Cheers

Comment: Just one other note. The indention that you're using in `verify` is **really** bad form. It makes it look like you're returning `false` if the `if` statement is true. But in reality, you're not. Not to mention the compile error (mis-matched braces). I'd suggest *always* using `{}` braces, but if not, *don't* indent the other branch like that. It will cause you pain in the future (as it indicates the opposite of its primary intent.

Something to think about at least...

Comment: Yeah, of course. I just erased a fragment of code, and left the indention as it was. It was a simple CTRL+C CTRL+V mistake. I hope now it looks better (edit). Thx for the note about it, +1.

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords. The guy who wrote the framework (SolarDesigner) is the same guy who wrote [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) and sits as a judge in the [Password Hashing Competition](http://password-hashing.net/). So he knows a thing or two about attacks on passwords.

Comment: Thx for a great link, +1 from me :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***As per OP's request:***

You can use the password compatibility pack if on PHP < 5.5

- **https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/**

This is especially useful when you wish to use PHP's 5.5 [`password_hash()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

Comment: It's deja vu all over again =)

Comment: LOL! Yep, but it could serve others based on their search. Who knows what'll pop up first on Google @JohnConde

Comment: You're quite welcome @Jacek Glad I could be of help.

Comment: Yeah, searched for this library no Google, and this is possible a duplicate question. But as I can't find the answer, I think it can be useful. Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Not a problem. You tried to research it and that's what counts. @Jacek Cheers